# Looking for a document that explains how to integrate vertx in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vert.x

I'm trying to run vertx from spring-boot.
Is there any tutorial or getting started document that explains how to do it?

Comment: For Vert.x 3.0:  

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/springboot-example  


https://github.com/rworsnop/vertx-beans


https://github.com/rworsnop/vertx-beans-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe spring-boot has not "native support" for vertx - see list of [spring boot starters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms).

Although I don't know vertx, you can use it with spring-boot the same way you would use it in any other spring application - [example](http://perfectworldprogramming.com/embed-vert-x-eventbus-into-your-spring-application-with-ease/) that google found.